# Execute an external application from Electron ASAR package

Tags: electron

I have built an electon app which includes an executable within the electron package.

When I am on development mode, I just access the file through /assets/executable, however, this doesn't seem to work when I built the package with ASAR.

How can I unpack and have the path to my resources within my electron package ?

Comment: Did you found any solution,Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do it, but this has always worked for me:

Make your own `resources` folder in your project's base directory, make a subdirectory called `extras`, and place your executables in it. Example:

```
- myApp
  - main
    -mainprocess.js
  - node_modules
  - renderer
    - renderer.html
    - renderer.js
  - resources
    - extras
      - ffmpeg.exe
  - package.json
```

After packaging the app, run an additional step that copies your extra resources to the packaged app's resources folder: On Windows, this command will do it, and can be put in a batch file:

```
xcopy "resources/extras" "release-builds/myApp-win32-x64/resources/extras" /i
```

This way when you reference the path to the executable in your code, it will be the same path for the packaged app as it is for the dev version.